# Removing set number of characters from end of string with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Simple request (hopefully) here.

I have a string which whilst it varies in length, will always need the last 6 characters removed.

Using a 3rd party web service, so I'm unable to edit the response in the XML before outputting.

If anyone can suggest a quick way of trimming them off i'd be really grateful!

here is the string i'll be using:

```
#daysEvent[iItem].XmlChildren[iEvent].XmlChildren[16].XmlText#
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
Left(mystring, len(mystring)-6)
```

Comment: Great! I think my brain has melted due to the fact it's hot and it's Friday. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It really is too bad that coldfusion does not support negative numbers in its string functions like many other languages do.

Comment: If enough people ask for it, it might get added - feature requests can be made here: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform

Comment: If we have <cfset currentDateTime=Now()> i.e. <cfset currentDateTime= "{ts '2014-08-19 02:33:07'}"> THEN <cfset currentDateTime = Left(currentDateTime, len(currentDateTime)-2)>
<cfset currentDateTime = Right(currentDateTime, len(currentDateTime)-5)> WILL RESULT 2014-08-19 02:33:07      :) :)